# How to create a stream of Span targets when user Selects a bunch of elements(spans) using mouse down,move and up on the target

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, rxjs, mouselistener

I have a situation like this.

```
<div id="container"><span>A</span><span>B</span><span>C</span><span>D</span><span>A</span><span>B</span><span>C</span><span>D</span><span>A</span><span>B</span><span>C</span><span>D</span></div>
```

When user starts mouse down on any span and moves around mouse and ends mouse move with mouseup on any other span, I need to capture(buffer) each and every span in between and use that as a stream which then I can subscribe to and get all span targets selected in this event. Is there a way to do it?

Here is what I currently have:

Signature for observableFromEventPattern:

```
    $.fn.collectSelectedSpintax = function(boundaryTarget) {

        //console.log(this);
        //console.log(boundaryTarget);

        if(!!boundaryTarget.hasClass('syns-grammar')) {
            boundaryTarget = boundaryTarget.parent();
        }

        var spans;

        if(boundaryTarget.isAfter(this)) {
            //Get NextUntil
        spans = this.nextUntil(boundaryTarget.next()).addBack();
        }
        else {
            //Prev Until
            //console.log('Going Back');
            spans = this.prevUntil(boundaryTarget.prev()).addBack();
        }


        return {
            selectedSpans: spans,
            selectedSpintax: spintaxFromSpans(spans)
        };
    };

    var observableFromEventPattern = function($parentEle, targetSelector, event){ ... }

    var mouseup = observableFromEventPattern($container, 'span', 'mouseup');
    var mouseMove = observableFromEventPattern($container, 'span', 'mousemove');
    var mouseDown = observableFromEventPattern($container, 'span', 'mousedown')
.map((event) => $(event.target));

    var mouseDrag = mouseDown.flatMap(($startTarget) => {
return mouseMove
    //.tap((event) => event.preventDefault())
    .map((event) => $(event.target))
    .filter(($target) => $startTarget[0] !== $target[0])
    .map(($target) => $startTarget.collectSelectedSpintax($target))
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .takeUntil(mouseup)
    .filter((obj) => validSpintax(obj.selectedSpintax));
```

});

This seems to work, however if I can make it more efficient for large selection of span using buffers, it'd be great.

Comment: @paulpdaniels Hey added what I currently have.